# Get directory of running screen session

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

In general, I have long simulations running on several screen sessions which can get confusing.

Is there a way to get the directory on which one specific screen session is on?

**EDIT:**
I just realized that the easiest thing to do is just to launch the job in the background... Nevertheless, my question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a command to `screen`, e.g., a shell script could do something like this (assuming the session is named *MySession*):

```
#!/bin/sh
myfile=$(mktemp)
screen -S MySession sh -c 'pwd >$myfile'
cat $myfile
rm -f $myfile
```

That seems to work only for the first window opened in a `screen` session (rather than for the currently active one).